# How to make a auditing funntionality in a PHP site

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´d like to make an auditing functionality in a PHP site.
Then, I think a good best way is to get the IP address from the source and insert each action from this IP in my database.

I thought about the steps below:

1. Get an IP address from the source and put this one in a session.
2. Each button in the site, when clicked, does its job and inserts this IP and the button's name and DateTime into the database.

Is this the best way?

So... as a result, for sample, I'd have a table like this:

```
+---+---------------+-------------+----------------------+
|Id | IP            | Button      | DateTime_Click       |
+---+---------------+------------------------------------+
|1  | 201.33.22.11  | Button_01   | 2020-06-15 10:03:28  |
+---+---------------+------------+-----------------------+
|2  | 202.44.33.22  | Button_02   | 2020-06-15 11:25:35  |
+---+---------------+------------------------------------+
|3  | 201.33.22.11  | Button_02   | 2020-06-15 12:36:28  |
+---+---------------+------------------------------------+
|4  | 203.11.11.33  | Button_01   | 2020-06-15 12:45:24  |
+---+---------------+------------------------------------+
```

I have some doubts because lots of IPs will access the php site and I need to insert into the database each click on the button from each IP source correctly.

How could I do it?
Can I have some examples?
Thanks so much!
Best

Comment: Why not just log it to the db when they enter the site?

Comment: I already log this one when it enters in the site, but I need to log each click on button to support auditing funtionality.

Comment: Why not just modify what you have to add a db entry on POST?

Comment: I don't know how to do. One stuff is get IP address from source when it enter into site and log it... Another stuff different is to get IP and keep it to use in sql statement for each button's click from this IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ip_address will get the ip the user is using. If you trust that the person being audited isn't using a spoofed ip address, this should work for you:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_POST['Button_01'])) {
  // You didn't provide any SQL query in your question, so make sure your connection to the database is made then add your SQL INSERT.
}
```